# Why must I use Dispose()?

Tags: c#, ado.net, dispose

Here is my code:

```
public void InsertData()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Some Simple Insert Query", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

But I found this code sample:

```
public void InsertData()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Some Simple Insert Query", connection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    command.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

why does the author use

> command.Dispose()

and

> connection.Dispose();

in their code?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 5):

`using` can only be used on objects that *are* disposable (which is when they implement the interface [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)). Doing so will automatically call `Dispose` on that instance. However in contrast to call it yourself the `using`-statement ensures that `Dispose` is also called when an exception whithin that block occurs. So it´s safer to use that approach.

Your first example is equivalent to this:

```
try 
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Some Simple Insert Query", connection);
    try 
    {            
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        command.Dispose();
    }
}
finally
{
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have *resource leak* when *exception* has been thrown:

```
public void InsertData()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Some Simple Insert Query", connection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <- imagine that this throws exception 

    // and so these don't execute at all and you'll have two resources leaked: 
    //  1. Connection
    //  2. Command
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

The reasons of the exception can vary:

```
1. Insert failed (e.g. invalid field value insertion)
2. User doesn't have privelege required
3. RDMBS Internal error 
...
```

You can emulate `using` with `try` .. `finally` which is *wordy*:

```
public void InsertData()
{
    SqlConnection connection = null;

    try {
      connection = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.ConnectionString);
      connection.Open();

      SqlCommand command = null;

      try {
         command = new SqlCommand("Some Simple Insert Query", connection);
         command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
      }
      finally { // rain or shine, dispose the resource (if it has been created)
        if (command != null)
          command.Dispose(); 
      }
    }
    finally { // rain or shine, dispose the resource (if it has been created)
      if (connection != null)
        connection.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use dispose in your example, because the using block does that for you.

See here: [using Statement (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: so "using" block does not need any "Dispose" method?

Comment: I would say that it's oposite `using` requires `Dispose` method but calls it for you. That's the difference.

Answer (score 3):

He is using `connection.Dispose();` because the person is inexperienced and is writing bad code that is not safe. If a exception is thrown the connection will never be disposed of causing it to remain open till the GC collects the connection maybe minutes or hours later.

Comment: The GC won´t ever close it anytime as it is a unmanaged ressource which the GC *can´t* handle at all. Not disposing a ressource simply produces a deadlock which is closed only on reboot.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The GC *may* be able to clean it up in a finalizer.  It's *possible* that it never gets cleaned up, but it's also possible that it will be.

Answer (score 3):

In .Net IDisposable and the Dispose method are used to clean up unmanaged resources.

.Net keeps track of managed resources so it can clean them up automatically, but it needs to have some help when dealing with unmanaged resources.

> Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx

The using statement is a way to automatically call the Dispose method when you're done using it.

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.

It'll even get called if an exception is called.

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

The code which isn't using the using statements is incorrect.

It'll work most of the time, but if an exception occurs the unmanaged resources in SqlConnection could be left uncleaned.

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using statement.

Answer (score 3):

The `using` block is just syntactic sugar for the `try`/`finally` `Dispose()` pattern. This is all explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Note you can also reduce the indentation in your code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Some Simple Insert Query", connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```